# mysql syntax for a beginner

Tags: mysql, syntax

Ok trying to get into mysql a little bit and I need something explained because the tutorial (w3schools) I'm reading doesn't explain nor does googling it turn up anything.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

- What does `id int(6)` mean? Is it creating a table with 6 null entrees?
- What is `varchar(30)` doing?
- Is `conn->query($sql)` just seeing if a table exist?

Comment: I have to caution you, w3schools is not really the best place to learn from. Start with [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) and branch out from there. If it's teaching you nonsense like testing `=== TRUE` you're already picking up really quirky habits that need to be addressed. If you're serious about learning application development take some time to look at what various [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) offer. 
[Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is particularly beginner friendly and yet is quite powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, w3 does explain. Here are all Mysql types:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp

Where you can see that int(6) means integer type with max 6 digits, and varchar(30) is string type with max 30 characters.

$conn->query is creating the table. For more information on what 'query' function does, you can just simply google 'mysqli query' and the first result will be this:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

As you can see, the return value can be FALSE on failure, or a truthy value, depending on the query type:

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Comment: So $conn->query creates the table and not whenever you declared $sql?  I thought $conn->query was just checking to see if the tbale was created successfully.

I was looking for a explanation on the page where they are creating a table lol.

Comment: $sql is just a variable that holds a string value. It can be anything, but in this case, it's a MySQL query. So, you pass that variable to the query function which executes the query, and returns a value, which basically says whether there was an error (FALSE) or not (truthy value, either TRUE or mysql_object).

Comment: The [official MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html) is vastly better than w3schools on any given subject and should be the first place to check. It's often way more specific, and the comments are quite helpful as they add additional explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The 6 and the 30, are the "length" of that variable, int(6) have a range from 0 to 2^6 since its unsigned, in the varchar, is the max number of characteres it can have.
Conn-Query its the command to execute the Query.